# the sqlite deletion method does not work in flutter either

Tags: flutter, sqlite

i'm making a todo app using sqlite deleteSqlite, it doesn't delete when the button is pressed during the deletion process, but I wonder why it deletes when it does hot resart?

```
  Future<void> _deleteTodoItem(int id, String text, bool isDone) async {
    await TodoModelDao().deleteTodo(id, text, isDone);
    refleshList();
  }
  Future<List<TodoModel>> _showAllData() async {
    var todoList = await TodoModelDao().getAllData();
    return todoList;
  }

  refleshList() {
    setState(() {
      _showAllData();
    });
  }
```

```
  Future<void> deleteTodo(int id, String text, bool isDone) async {
    var db = await DatabaseHelper.dbAccess();

    await db.delete(TABLENAME, where: "$ID = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }
  Future<List<TodoModel>> getAllData() async {
    var db = await DatabaseHelper.dbAccess();

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLENAME");

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      var row = maps[i];
      return TodoModel(id: row[ID], text: row[TEXT]);

    });
  }
```

```
child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _deleteTodoItem(widget.todoModel.id, widget.todoModel.text,
                  widget.todoModel.isDone);
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
            color: Coloors.whiteColor,
            iconSize: 18,
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does delete, but flutter is unaware that you want to re-render ui after deletion.
When you hot restart, it re-renders it.There are many work around this. 
One simple solution would be calling `setState` to force re-render.
You can try replacing some part of your code (`IconButton`) with the following.

```
child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
             await _deleteTodoItem(widget.todoModel.id, widget.todoModel.text,
                  widget.todoModel.isDone);
              // force re-render ui
              setState(() {
                // update your variable here...
                 _showAllData();
             });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
            color: Coloors.whiteColor,
            iconSize: 18,
          ),
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but I have to say it's not working.

Comment: That's because you haven't posted the full code. 
I have edited my answer to better understsand.

Comment: i recreated the project

Comment: @FurkanBalcı, if any issues, let me know please. Also you can post your issue and let me know. Thanks :)